# Inserting into multiple tables at once based on a value you insert into one table first

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, insert

I'm trying to create a row in multiple tables at once.  The problem I'm running into is all the tables except the first table need the autonumber/primary key from the first INSERT statement.  I'm not entirely sure what VALUE to enter in the tables beyond the first.  Help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub cmdCreate_Click()

    If DCount("*", "[tblRegSR]", "[WorkOrderID] = " & Me![txtID]) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "This record already exists", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Duplicate Record"
    Else
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblRegSR (WorkOrderID, CustomerID) VALUES (Me!txtID.Value, Me!Customer.Value)"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbFirstSR (ServiceRecordID) VALUES (WhatGoesHere)"

    End If
End Sub
```

WhatGoesHere would typically be the ID field of the first table I inserted data into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblRegSR (WorkOrderID, CustomerID) VALUES (Me!txtID.Value, Me!Customer.Value)"
```

Assuming you have a field called ID in tblRegSR as AutoNumber, you would insert it into the 2nd table like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert into tblFirstSR (ServiceRecordID) Select Max(ID) from tblRegSR "
```

Comment: That works, however it's bringing up more errors, ugh.  This is probably unrelated so if needed, I'll post a new question for this specifically.

When I click the button, it asks me for the values of Me!txtID and Me!Customer.

They both exist on the form (which is a subform within another form - but the button is on the subform itself).  txtID is a simple textbox, Customer is a combobox where column 0 is bound to ID but it's not displayed.

Then, after the notices to append a record, it tells me it can't append the first table (tblRegSR) saying there is a key violation.

Comment: Key violation has to do with inserting duplicates in your primary key field. You might have ServiceReocrdID saved as PrimaryKey. It's hard to tell when I can't see what your tables looks like. Check this out for some help maybe: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-reference-an-access-subform-107106/

Comment: I have the column ServiceRecordID set as NUMBER (Indexed - Duplicates Ok).  The only primary keys I have in any of my tables are the ID fields. 

Do I need to do anything special for controls I reference on the same form the button control is on?  I thought it would just be a Me!txtID, but perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: You said your controls are inside a subform. Try using this syntax: Forms![FormName]![SubformName].Form![ControlName]. Otherwise post a new question